# Welch Bounds for correlations

Tags: correlation, equality, bounds, cross-correlation

I am working on correlations and trying to find optimized codes for transmission. In this regard, Welch lays down a bound for correlations, based on number of sequences and the length of these communication sequences.

The proof is vaguely given in his publication of 1974; can anyone refer to me to a simpler tutorial with simpler mathematics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Welch Bound proof on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch_bounds) is the most basic explanation. There are alternate proofs in various literature, as well.